# Brain Tree unable to escrow payment using nodejs

Tags: node.js, braintree

```js
var charge = {
    merchantAccountId: 'trinisofttechnologies

> yead

',
    serviceFeeAmount: '1.00',
    amount: '100.00',
    paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
    options: {
      submitForSettlement: true,
      holdInEscrow: true
    }
  }

gateway.transaction.sale(charge, function (err, result) {
    console.log(err, result);
    if(err || !result.success){
      res.end("Payment Failed: "+(result && result.message));
    }else{
      gateway.transaction.holdInEscrow(result.transaction.id, function (err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
        if(err || !result.success){
          res.end("Payment Failed: "+(result && result.message));
        }else{
          res.end("Payment hold in escrow!");
        }
      });
    }
  });

// Service fee not supported on master merchant account. Transaction could not be held in escrow.
```

Comment: @moderator, I am unable to modify the the question, I want to remote "> yeah" and format the charge JSON

Comment: Looks like this is being handled over in [Github](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node/issues/65).

Comment: Hi, I am facing this issue now.  Did you solve it by having to create sub-merchants, then charging THOSE sub-merchants, then getting the escrow to work?